# A comparison between "Baggage", "Luggage" and "Suitcase(s)"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, sentence-meaning, difference

I was wondering whether there is any difference between the following sentences using the words "[baggage](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/us/amp/english/baggage)", "[luggage](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/us/amp/english/luggage)" and "[suitcase](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/us/amp/english/suitcase)":

**Example 1:**

> 1.1. Could you please help me sir? I have lost my **baggage**. 
> 1.2. Could you please help me sir? I have lost my **luggage**. 
> 1.3. Could you please help me sir? I have lost my **suitcases / suitcase**.

**Example 2:**

> 2.1. We have to leave early morning tomorrow. Have you packed your **baggage**? 
> 2.2. We have to leave early morning tomorrow. Have you packed your **luggage**? 
> 2.3. We have to leave early morning tomorrow. Have you packed your **suitcase / suitcases**?

To me, all three sentences in each set mean the same and the only difference is the grammatical usage; "baggage and luggage" are collective / uncountable nouns while "suitcase" is countable.

Comment: Well, of course baggage/luggage could include other things than suitcases (trunks, rucksacks, bags...). Baggage and luggage are more or less synonymous. The dictionary link you provide suggests that _baggage_ is more common in American English.

Comment: Well, considering what you pointed out (baggage/luggage could include other things than suitcases), I think in this cases, these three sentences mean the same. Do you agree @Kate Bunting?

Comment: Yes, assuming that the speaker knows that what you will be taking on the journey is a suitcase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Baggage and luggage in their main meanings have almost the exact same meaning. Some people try to make a distinction between "baggage" which is carried and "luggage" which is dragged.  But actual use doesn't support this difference.  Both words have a long tradition in English and are about equally common.

Baggage has a number of metaphorical meanings such as "Emotional baggage". And there is an insult, to call a woman an "old baggage". (don't use this)

A suitcase is a particular item that could be used for baggage/luggage.  Instead of a suitcase you could use a backpack, a rucksack,  a sports bag. You could even put your luggage in a cardboard box.

So in your examples, all three are correct and idiomatic.

Comment: 'An old bag' surely, if one were so crass.

Comment: Supposing that **there is only one suitcase** then will they mean the same thing again @James K?

Comment: @JMB both bag and baggage are used (taming of the shrew for example, Kate says she won't be called baggage).  Yes, all three are correct and idiomatic whether you say "your suitcase" or "your suitcases".